# Wrap words with spans after entering text into textarea

Tags: jquery

My scenario is similar to those live commenting tutorials we've all seen: type text into a textarea & have it display somewhere else on the page while you type. I have the live text input sorted using David Walsh's jQuery tutorial at http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-comment-preview .

**Is there a way for me to wrap each word with a span tag in the ouputted div area as well?**

You can see my progress at: http://jsfiddle.net/mrmartineau/epdwm/

P.S. it would be lovely to output the text using p tags instead of one long line of text with line breaks, like the question entry form here does.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/epdwm/4/

---

updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epdwm/6/

the important part is the: `.replace(/( |, |\. )/g,'[/span]$1[span]')`
if you want to add more punctuation, add them in the expression.

hope this helps

Comment: Hi Andy, after using sunn0's answer initially, I changed to use yours because it was better at wrapping the spans. Do you know if there's a way to exclude punctuation from being wrapped?

Currently, if there was a sentence like 'The cat sat on the mat, while looking at the sky' there would be a span around 'mat,' like so: 
&lt;span>mat,&lt;/span> 
but I would rather have it like this:
&lt;span>mat&lt;/span>,

Comment: thank you so much Andy, this is brilliant! After a bit of fiddling with regular expressions (my first foray..) at http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex# I have now got what I believe to be a bullet proof setup.

BTW, this is the regex I am currently using: .replace(/( |"|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]|'|: |, |\.)/g,'</span>$1<span>')

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the expected result correctly (p instead of line breaks and span between around each word).

http://jsfiddle.net/epdwm/5/

Comment: You probably need to switch the two lines doing p and span respectively. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes I noticed that & changed it. Is there a way to exclude punctuation from the scenario? I mean, I would still like it there but not wrapped in span tags...

Comment: For more advanced parsing use regex as in Andy:s answer.